# Why do I get "no credentials cache" error when mounting Kerberized NFS share?

Tags: centos, nfs, kerberos

I have two systems on a local network, nfsclient (CentOS 7) and nfsserver (CentOS 6).  These names correctly resolve to their IP addresses, and Kerberos is working between them (nfsserver is the KDC).  I have a Kerberized NFSv4 share exported on nfsserver; my /etc/exports is as follows:

```
/export                 *(rw,sync,fsid=0,no_subtree_check,sec=krb5p)                   
/export/home            *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,sec=krb5p)
```

I can see these exports from nfsclient:

```
[root@nfsclient ~]# showmount -e nfsserver
Export list for nfsserver:
/export/home *
/export      *
```

If I remove the sec=krb5p options in /etc/exports, I can mount the share from nfsclient using

```
[root@nfsclient ~]# mount -t nfs4 nfsserver:/ /mnt/nfs
```

When NFS is Kerberized, however, things don't go as well:

```
[root@nfsclient ~]# mount -t nfs4 -o sec=krb5p nfsserver:/ /mnt/nfs
mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting nfsserver:/
```

This is accompanied by a series of repeated error messages in /var/log/messages:

```
Jun 22 19:55:02 oxo gssproxy: gssproxy[769]: (OID: { 1 2 840 113554 1 2 2 }) Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information, No credentials cache found
Jun 22 19:55:02 oxo gssproxy: gssproxy[769]: (OID: { 1 2 840 113554 1 2 2 }) Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information, No credentials cache found
Jun 22 19:55:02 oxo gssproxy: gssproxy[769]: (OID: { 1 2 840 113554 1 2 2 }) Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information, No credentials cache found
Jun 22 19:55:02 oxo gssproxy: gssproxy[769]: (OID: { 1 2 840 113554 1 2 2 }) Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information, No credentials cache found
Jun 22 19:55:02 oxo gssproxy: gssproxy[769]: (OID: { 1 2 840 113554 1 2 2 }) Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information, No credentials cache found
Jun 22 19:55:02 oxo gssproxy: gssproxy[769]: (OID: { 1 2 840 113554 1 2 2 }) Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information, No credentials cache found
```

Nothing shows up in the logs on the server.  Running klist on the client shows that root has a credentials cache at /tmp/krb5cc_0, so I'm led to think there's a problem with gss-proxy.

/etc/gssproxy/gssproxy.conf:

```
[gssproxy]

[service/HTTP]
  mechs = krb5
  cred_store = keytab:/etc/gssproxy/http.keytab
  cred_store = ccache:/var/lib/gssproxy/clients/krb5cc_%U
  euid = 48

[service/nfs-server]
  mechs = krb5
  socket = /run/gssproxy.sock
  cred_store = keytab:/etc/krb5.keytab
  trusted = yes
  kernel_nfsd = yes
  euid = 0

[service/nfs-client]
  mechs = krb5
  cred_store = keytab:/etc/krb5.keytab
  cred_store = ccache:FILE:/var/lib/gssproxy/clients/krb5cc_%U
  cred_store = client_keytab:/var/lib/gssproxy/clients/%U.keytab
  cred_usage = initiate
  allow_any_uid = yes
  trusted = yes
  euid = 0
```

So gss-proxy must be looking for the credentials cache in /var/lib/gssproxy/clients.  It's also getting keys from /etc/krb5.keytab (which has keys for the principals nfs/nfsclient and host/nfsclient).  However, /var/lib/gssproxy/clients seems to always be empty on nfsclient.

Am I missing something here?  I can't figure out what exactly is going wrong with mounting this share.

Comment: Worth highlighting that the NFS-Server is running *CentOS 6*, while NFS-Client is *CentOS 7*.  Additionally, it would help if the specific minor versions of the OSs were provided as well as the specific versions of the packages installed/used on both servers.  Also, how the overall configuration was done; i.e.. using _FreeIPA_/_IdM_ or not.  Lastly, what happens if the sub-folder is mounted? As a result, additional, different errors might be displayed and provide helpful hints to the root cause of the failures.

Comment: You can also check your `/etc/sssd` configuration to see if SSSD is being used for credentials caching.  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/Configuring_Domains.html

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with the default file config in defining the path of the  cache.  Try with this configuration of the client, in `/etc/gssproxy/gssproxy.conf`:

```
[service/nfs-client]
  mechs = krb5
  cred_store = keytab:/etc/krb5.keytab
  cred_store = ccache:FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_%U
  cred_usage = initiate
  allow_any_uid = yes
  trusted = yes
  euid = 0
  debug = true
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your client is joined to the domain.

```
ipa-client-install --force-join
```

Then ensure you have a ticket

```
kinit admin
```

and  then double check the krb5.keytab

```
restorecon -v /etc/krb5.keytab
```

ensure your client is in the keytab

```
kinit -k

host/ < client > . < domain > @REALM
```

You should then be able to mount with `sec=krb5p`